# Problem making a cloth

Tags: modeling, physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to make a cloth and they do not sew completely

[image]

So the armpit area is not fully sewed as you can see.

The cloth is made by just sewing two planes.

[image]
[image]

Above is modifier (left) & physics (right) tabs of the cloth highlighted in yellow in the first pic.

[image]

Also above is the physics tab of the black body.

What I want to happen are :

1. make them fully stitch to each other without those gaps
2. Currently they have sharp edges and I want them to have smooth edge

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you all beforehand and let me know if you need any other information

[image]

Comment: Try making the cloth bigger or stretchier. I suspect it simply isn’t big enough to fit your model.

Comment: Please try to find a descriptive title for your question, thanks.

Comment: Please can you share the .blend file. I need to inspect the file to give an answer. Thing is, with stuff like cloth and other simulations, you can't get an answer without inspecting and experimenting. Also please share which version of blender you are using.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=AqNq39Ek" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/AqNq39Ek/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for helping me, above is the link to file

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, your cloth is too small to fit your model. This could be due to your Collision settings being set to have too large an Outer limit (0.1).

Either reduce Outer, increase the size of your garment or reduce the Shrinking Factor to make it slightly larger (it can be negative to indicate it should 'grow' instead of 'shrink').

Once you have the garment fitting, you can apply the cloth and join the vertices so that you can avoid the slight remaining gap (due to the force of the collision as it rests on the surface) and avoid the sharp edge/crease of the join.